# AngularJS: How to get subcategories based on category selection

Tags: angularjs

### My question

Please how to get subcategories of specific category selected ?
Here I can retrieve all data but not filtered by categories.

Thanks

### Json Data

```
"data": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "famille": "subcat1",
  "catproduit_id": 2,
  "catproduit": {
    "id": 2,
    "cat": "cat2",
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "famille": "subcat2",
  "catproduit_id": 2,
  "catproduit": {
    "id": 2,
    "cat": "cat2",
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "famille": "subcat3",
  "catproduit_id": 1,
  "catproduit": {
    "id": 1,
    "cat": "cat1",
  }
},
}
]
```

### Controller

```
 "use strict";

 var app = angular.module('bb-laravel',['ui.select']);
 app.controller('RapportCreateCtrl',function($scope,SweetAlert,RapportService,CatproduitService,FamproduitService,$http,$rootScope,$translatePartialLoader,Notification,trans){


/*
 * Define initial value
 */
$scope.tmp = {};
$scope.rapport={};

/*
 * Create a rapport
 */
$scope.create = function(rapport) {
    $scope.isDisabled = true;
    $scope.tmp = angular.isObject(rapport) ? angular.toJson(rapport) : rapport;
    RapportService.create($scope.tmp);
};


/*
 * Get all Catproduit
 */
CatproduitService.list().then(function(data){
    $scope.catproduits = data;
});

/*
 * Get all Famproduit
 */
FamproduitService.list().then(function(data){
    $scope.famproduits = data;
});

/********************************************************
 * Event Listeners
 * Rapport event listener related to RapportCreateCtrl
 ********************************************************/

$scope.$on('rapport.create', function() {
    $scope.rapport ={};
    Notification({message: 'rapport.form.rapportAddSuccess' ,templateUrl:'app/vendors/angular-ui-notification/tpl/success.tpl.html'},'success');
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
});

//Validation error in create rapport event listener
$scope.$on('rapport.validationError', function(event,errorData) {
    Notification({message: errorData ,templateUrl:'app/vendors/angular-ui-notification/tpl/validation.tpl.html'},'warning');
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
});

});
```

### HTML Form

And I have the select of categories and subcategories like this:

```
 ...
                  <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                Catégorie des produits
                            </label>
                            <ui-select ng-model="rapport.catproduit_id" theme="select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Selectionner une catécorie">
                                    {{$select.selected.cat || $select.selected}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="catproduit.id as catproduit in catproduits | propertyFilter: {cat: $select.search}">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="catproduit.cat | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                Famille des produits
                            </label>
                            <ui-select ng-model="rapport.famproduit_id" theme="select2" style="width: 100%;">
                                <ui-select-match placeholder="Selectionner une famille des produits">
                                    {{$select.selected.famille || $select.selected}}
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="famproduit.id as famproduit in famproduits | propertyFilter: {famille: $select.search}">
                                    <div ng-bind-html="famproduit.famille | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                        </div>
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can transfer array data to map. The key of the map is father category id.So when father category selected, Map[selectedCategory] is the subcategories.

Comment: Thanks @lepdou for your reply, good approach but can you please show me how to use this ?